# Microsoft sculpt keyboard not working with Mac book pro

Tags: mac, hardware-failure

I bought new sculpt keyboard fresh from store and used a 2 different  connectors to convert to type c and plugged in to mac book pro yet with no luck. It's weird that mouse and number pads are working but the keyboard is not. Any help ?

Comment: As it's new, just take it back to the shop.